# How is the center pin supported in air-filled coaxial cables?

Tags: rf, transmission-line, microwave, coax, coaxial

In SMA cables, the PTFE dielectric supports the center pin through the length of cable.

How is the center pin supported in air-filled cables? E.g., 3.5mm, 2.9mm, K-connector, 1.8mm, V-connector, etc. I assume that there must be disks of dielectric at some regular distance to help support the pin, but I have no idea.

Comment: Have you spoken with the manufacturer or, have you read the data sheet? Demonstrate some research effort and put links in your question.

Comment: In the highest quality air-spaced lines, ie for calibration, the centre is unsupported, at least not supported in the line itself. When you open the foam-lined box, there's an outer, and an inner, in their separate compartments. The trick is the inner is designed to be used between particular connectors, and it mates with those to support it. Can be tricky to assemble.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They use some type of spacer, the exact type depends on manufacturer.

One common type is a helical spacer of a dielectric material such as polyethylene. Other types are similar, some form of plastic framework that uses just enough material to support the center conductor but leave the space between the center and outer conductors mostly air filled.